# Point Cloud Segmentation

Tags: 3d, point-clouds

I have the point cloud of propeller.
The problem is I want to separate/segment the wing of propeller from the main body of propeller, because I just need to focus on the points on the wing
I also have the normals on every point.
Do you have any suggestion to separate it?

Thank you guys.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are my ideas.
Try cylinder fitting from PCL (Point Cloud Library). That might  give you the right segmentation results.
http://vml.sakura.ne.jp/koeda/PCL/tutorials/html/cylinder_segmentation.html

Another way is to Apply PCA to normals and see if you can retrieve meaningful dimensions.
Or Simple k-means clustering on normals.

If any of these don’t work, using tSNE to visualize those normals might give you some clues to figure out the way to separate them based on some thresholds as well.